# Windows XP - who is connected remotely?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, remote

Is there any simple way to check who is currently connected to Windows XP computer using the command line? Information that I need is in Windows Task Manager/Users.

I need to know Client Name, not just user, because everybody logs in with the same credentials.

There is command `qwinsta` which returns many information, but not Client Name.
Is there any other command?

Comment: `qwinsta` is for RDP, not client sessions.

Comment: How are you issuing the command being that XP does not allow concurrent connections? Is this being run remotely against the workstaion, inside a service, you want to look at the history?

Answer (score 1):

I can't check but I think something like [net use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) or maybe [net session](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_session.mspx?mfr=true). One of those [net commands](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) anyway.

Comment: `net session` is the correct way as it shows machines names that each session originates from.

Comment: net session returns only sessions related to for example samba connections. This command doesn't list remote desktop connections (it returns "There are no entries in the list.")